# Fast buffered Image compression

Tags: java, image-processing

Wondering if anyone knows a  fast way to compress buffered JPEG images with Java. In my program I'm taking in a ton of images using the robot class and I need compress them so i can save them a lot faster using file IO or put them into an array list. (I don't really mind going from really high quality images to average quality)

Comment: It is much faster to write them than to compress them. I think you're just writing them in a bad way. Queue them up to a thread and have the thread write them in a loop.

Comment: I ran into this with Robot. The problem was that the way Robot was implemented was just too slow. IIRC it dealt with memory in a very inefficient way. At the time I felt the only way around the problem would have been to write my own native code/JNI bridge and blast it to a NativeByteBuffer.

Comment: Have you tried writing them out concurrently? Breaking them up into batches and processing each group simultaneously.

Comment: @davidSchwartz yeah u were write i wasn't queuing them properly

Comment: ok I made it save images much much faster without file compression. The while loop where i was originally just ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image" + imageNumber) i replaced it where i made a new short lived thread that took in the image and did the same fileIO operation.The only problem i have now is when i increase the speed a lot more which is where the robot class cant keep up but i think that would be another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("someFile.jpg"))` isn't fast enough?

Comment: image io is an expensive operation, the `ImageIO.write(....)` is most likely the fastest you will find without a lot of quality reduction

Comment: Yup seems like your right i'll try processing my images a diffreint way, which might perhaps not require writing them to the hard disk drive