# Java - How can I compress a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, compression, bufferedimage

Also, which method (jpeg, png, gif) is best for compression in terms of bandwith?

Comment: Check this : http://www.ou.edu/class/digitalmedia/articles/CompressionMethods_Gif_Jpeg_PNG.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722020/fast-buffered-image-compression

Answer (score 5):

**What format to use:**

- **[JPG/JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)** is lossey compression- you will lose detail. (The quality level is controllable, which helps)
- **[GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gif)** is lossless compression, BUT its conversion to an 8-bit color space distorts many images, especially natural ones.
- **[PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)** is lossless compression.

Unless you have a compelling reason to not use PNG, I would recommend it. [More details](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30941/whats-the-difference-between-jpg-png-and-gif/)

With the same image, but using different formats, image quality is usually approximately inverse to image size. I would recommend using PNG and if your PNGs are too large, use JPEG. PNGs also have the benefit of supporting transparency.

GIFs are really only good for small computer generated images like icons or typography. The above link also contains a image size comparison.

As always, the best test is to try them all for *your* application and compare; however, PNG is a reasonable default for most situations where the return value of such an analysis in minimal.

**Creating the JPEG, PNG or GIF:**

As far as actually creating the JPEG, PNG or GIF from the Java `BufferedImage`. Check out [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) from Sun/Oracle. There is lots of content that will help you, and the [last section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) explicitly addresses creating JPEG, PNG and GIFs. Here is a modified snip-it from the above linked tutorial:

```
try {
    BufferedImage bufImg = getBufferedImage(); //get BufferedImage from your code...
    File fout = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(bufImg, "png", fout);
} catch (IOException e) {
    //handle exception...
}
```

Comment: But how do I compress it in the first place?

Comment: Edited to address your question :)

Answer (score 2):

Compression is handled by the various file formats themselves (JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc).

The "best in terms of bandwidth" is a totally subjective question depending on the size and content of the images themselves.

For example, small images with a small number of colors and little "smoothing" (e.g. pixel graphics) will do well with PNG and GIF format.  Larger images with many colors and lots of smoothing (e.g. photographs) will do better with [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) and with that format you also have control over the compression/quality during encoding.

Answer (score 1):

JPEG most likely. It is default 75% compression, but the quality is lacking.

If you want quality: use png. You get transparency, which jpg doesn't support. The quality for pngs is also listed as 100%. If you want nice quality, but low file sizes you can always use png and use a compression type, similar to base-64 for the file. Then just decompress it and store the image. It will use low memory amounts to store the image, but will allow you to effectively still keep the quality intact.